# php file get the last id from mysql

Tags: php, html

I try to get the title and mess in last id5, [this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REt8c.jpg).

php code :

```
<?php
$hostname_mus_db = "localhost";
$database_mus_db = "message";
$username_mus_db = "root";
$password_mus_db = "";
$tf=@mysql_connect($hostname_mus_db,$username_mus_db,$password_mus_db);
if(!$tf)
die('Connection problem1 ..');
$tf_db=mysql_select_db($database_mus_db);
if(!$tf_db)
{
    @mysql_close($tf_handle);
    die('selection problem2 ..');
}
$co_array=array();
//if (isset($_GET['co'])) {
   // $co=$_GET['co'];
          $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mha1 where id>'1'"); /// here i edit the variable
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
          $co_array[]=$row;
      }
   // }
header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode(array("date"=>$co_array));
?>
```

in first the code is :

```
<?php
$hostname_mus_db = "localhost";
$database_mus_db = "message";
$username_mus_db = "root";
$password_mus_db = "";
$tf=@mysql_connect($hostname_mus_db,$username_mus_db,$password_mus_db);
if(!$tf)
die('Connection problem1 ..');
$tf_db=mysql_select_db($database_mus_db);
if(!$tf_db)
{
    @mysql_close($tf_handle);
    die('selection problem2 ..');
}
$co_array=array();
if (isset($_GET['co'])) {
    $co=$_GET['co'];

          $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mha1 where id>".$co);
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
          $co_array[]=$row;
      }
    }
header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode(array("date"=>$co_array));
?>
```

but the result was

[image: frist result]

How can I fix it ?? how can I make the result is just id 5 not all id.

Comment: @mohammedmrzouk.  Not sure I understand, but try: `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mha1 where id = 5");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i understand your question correctly.

If you want to know the last entry in a table and id is your primary key, use DESCENDING ORDER AND LIMIT

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM mha1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

If you insert a new dataset and want to know the last inserted id you can use insert_id

```
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mha1 (id) VALUES ('')"); 
 $last_id=mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: yas I want  insert a new dataset and want to know the last inserted id you can use insert_id , can u edit my code pleas

Comment: if (isset($_GET['co'])) {
    $co=$_GET['co'];
 
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mha1 (id) VALUES ('".trim(addslashes($co))."')"); 
 $last_id=mysql_insert_id();
          $co_array[]=$last_id;
   }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can just get all the results with this query in descending order then last inserted id is on top then fetch eaisly.
`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,1 ");`

Answer (score 0):

Please just change this part:

```
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mha1 where id>".$co);
```

to this:

```
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mha1 where id=".$co);
```

then `$co` can be an value of id you want.